# Count the number of sub strings irrespective of case sensitivity

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need to find the number of instances of substring `when` in a larger string irrespective of the case sensitivity, how do I efficiently do that ?

String:

> When people fail to answer a yes/no question with the words “yes” or
> “no” before elaborating. That is, when the task of determining the
> actual answer to the question (yes/no) is left up to the person who
> asked it. Like this:
>
> Me: Do you want tacos for dinner tonight?
>
> Them: I want pizza.
>
> Me: [Thinking: So… the answer to my actual question is “no.”]
>
> Or…
>
> Me: Did you do your homework?
>
> Them: I left it at home.
>
> Me: [Thinking **when**: So… the answer to my actual question is “yes.”]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just convert the string to lowercase before counting?

```py
>>> a = 'WHEN when WhEn wHeN'
>>> a.lower().count('when')
4
```

Comment: Seems fine for me.